# Postman: 'Exceeded maxRedirects' error while trying to GET request Chrome Web Store Item

Tags: node.js, redirect, https, get, postman

In Postman, when attempting to send a GET request to: https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/nlloamlgdioincflcopfgkbikjgaiihg

I get:
`Error: Exceeded maxRedirects. Probably stuck in a redirect loop https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/smoothzoom-%E2%80%93-quick-page-z/nlloamlgdioincflcopfgkbikjgaiihg`

Similarly, in JS fetch I get: `TypeError: Too many redirects.`

In the browser network tab, I can see that the response status code is 302 Found, and there's a Location header pointing to https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/smoothzoom-%E2%80%93-quick-page-z/nlloamlgdioincflcopfgkbikjgaiihg

I've tried:

- Enabled automatic redirection in Postman settings and checked maximum number of redirects.
- I've inspected the original request and ensured that all headers, including cookies, are replicated in the request in Postman.

I also tried a GET request to the final location, which is:
https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/smoothzoom-%E2%80%93-quick-page-z/nlloamlgdioincflcopfgkbikjgaiihg

If no headers are set, **the same error appears (Exceeded maxRedirects)**. However, if I only put the User-Agent header that I copied from the browser, I finally get the HTML of a website.

**What's causing the maxRedirects error?**

FWIW: My goal is to create a scraper in Node.js for a given extension ID without using an automation library such as Puppeteer, if anyone has any suggestions, thank you.